# Resharper C++ for VS for Desktop

Tags: c++, visual-studio, resharper

So I am in college and by this fact I have an opportunity to have a Resharper for free. Currently I write in C++, so I downloaded a Resharper for C++ and I've tried to install it. I've got three different VS versions:

- Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise
- Visual Studio 2013 for Windows Desktop
- Visual Studio 2012 for Windows Desktop

When I try to install Resharper I only see the option to install it to VS 2015. Is there no option to install it on 2012/2013 version? (I got Desktop version, cuz they are a lot of lighter and faster on my laptop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that 2012 and 2013 versions are the Express editions (which is implied from the names), then ReSharper won't work as these versions don't support extensions and plugins.

You need the full versions of Visual Studio to get this functionality.

As an aside, I'm not sure why you need to install *three* versions of Visual Studio. Won't the latest version do?

Comment: It's to laggy on my laptop... How can I get full Desktop version (got full access to DreamSpark)